# Capitalize the first letter

Tags: android

i am confused why my code isn't capitalizing my first letter, i am getting the name of the user from the database with all letters lower case.

here is the code:

```
    String email = null;
    String name = null;
    StringBuilder nameSB = new StringBuilder();
    nameSB.append(name);
    nameSB.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(nameSB.charAt(0)));
    name = nameSB.toString();

    try {
        email = ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getEmail();
        name = ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getFirstName() + " " + ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getLastName();

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    }
```

Comment: Debug it and you will get solution by yourself.

Comment: I, too, am confused by your code...can you debug it for me please?

Comment: move line 3 to 7 to below your try catch.

Comment: @AngelKoh thank you that worked :) ...

Comment: @AngelKoh Suggestion: turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @AngelKoh ... **before** someone else does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarising as answer

```
String email = null;
String name = null;
StringBuilder nameSB = new StringBuilder();

try {
    email = ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getEmail();
    name = ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getFirstName() + " " + ((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).getLastName();

    nameSB.append(name);
    nameSB.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(nameSB.charAt(0)));
    name = nameSB.toString();

} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
}
```